# R code to determine the combination of ni and nj that produce the smallest LSD, and assign these to the variable best.n_i and best.n_j

Tags: r

Calculate values of LSD from(lsd <- 2.085963447*sqrt(0.124611*(1/n_i + 1/n_j))), for values of ni from 2, . . . , 8 and nj from 8, . . . , 2, by creating two different vectors for ni and nj . Use these to compute LSD for combinations of (ni, nj) = (2, 8), (3, 7), . . . , (7, 3), (8, 2). You should be able to do this by redefining n_i and n_j from the first exercise and copying the code that assigns a value to lsd.

Write code to determine the combination of ni and nj that produce the smallest LSD, and assign these to the variable best.n_i and best.n_j. Assign the minimum LSD value to best.LSD. (Hint - use the functions min and which).

**Solution:** I have solved it partially but Im not able to understand how to find best.n_i and best.n_j. I know I need to use which function. Here is my solution:

```
n_i<-c(2:8)

n_i

n_j<-c(8:2)

n_j

print(lsd <- 2.085963447*sqrt(0.124611*(1/n_i + 1/n_j)))

best.lsd <-min((lsd <- 2.085963447*sqrt(0.124611*(1/n_i + 1/n_j))))

best.lsd



best.n_i <- which.min(lsd <- 2.085963447*sqrt(0.124611*(1/n_i + 1/n_j)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `best.n_i` tells you the position in the vector with the minimum value. It results in 4, meaning the 4th element. So to get the best value for `n_i` you use:

`n_i[best.n_i]`

which should result in 5. Similarly the best value for `n_j` would be:

`n_j[best.n_i]`

Comment: I am very new here can you tell me, how can I accept answer.

Comment: It is saying that vote cast by less than 15 reputation is recorded but do not change public displayed vote score. (see link https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation )

Answer (score 1):

best.lsd <- Inf

best.n_i <- Inf

best.n_j <- Inf

## Assign the variables

n_i <- 2:8

n_j <- 8:2

## Compute the lsd vector

lsd <- 2.085963447*sqrt(0.124611*(1/n_i + 1/n_j))

## Assign the associated vectors to lsd_df

lsd_df <- data.frame(n_i,n_j,lsd)

## Subset lsd_df to find the minimum combination of n_i and n_j

lsd_df <- lsd_df[which.min(lsd_df$lsd),]

## Assign the minimum values to the associated variable names

best.lsd <- lsd_df$lsd

best.n_i <- as.numeric(lsd_df$n_i)

best.n_j <- as.numeric(lsd_df$n_j)